# if boolean array true then fill it with a String (multidimensional)

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I wonder if it's possible to fill a multidimensional boolean Array with a string.

Let's imagine we are making Battleship Game something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[][] board = new boolean[5][5];

    board[3][2] = true;
    board[0][0] = true;

    for (boolean[] line : board
         ) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
    }

}
```

Now is it possible to change all the Values to be **" [ ] "** if its *false* and to be **" [X] "** if its *true* but still keep the boolean values?

Comment: Use an inner loop and `if` statements...You can't change the values of the `boolean` array to `Strings` but you can print `Strings` instead of `boolean` values.

Comment: "*if boolean array true then fill it with a String*" - No. A boolean array can hold only `boolean`s.

Comment: Well you can always do a `replaceAll("true", "[X]").replaceAll("false", "[ ]")` on output string.

Comment: @DawidPura Why `replaceAll` and not simply `replace`?

Comment: I think u r misleading because of some other language concepts like `C `or any but don't forget this is java where Boolean only accepts either "true" or "false" neither a string ,char or int.. 
But u may get help of any collection class.. I am sure u will got d solution. Thanks

Comment: @Pshemo you are right, I forget that is not a regexp :)

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious solutrion is to use an `Object` instead of a `boolean`. You can then override it's `toString` method.

```
class Square {

    private boolean taken;

    public boolean getTaken() {
        return taken;
    }

    public void setTaken(boolean taken) {
        this.taken = taken;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return taken ? "X" : " ";
    }

}

public void test() {
    Square[][] board = new Square[5][5];
}
```

And who knows where that will lead - perhaps even (gasp) a `Board` object!

```
class Board {

    Square[][] board = new Square[5][5];

    public Board() {
        for (Square[] row : board) {
            for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
                row[j] = new Square();
            }
        }
    }

}
```